# INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint (Inserting into table problem)

Tags: sql-server, string, binary, truncated

I'm working on a database and have a check constraint set for the phone number. But i have problem while inputting the phone number.

I tried inserting the phone number without the '' but still did not work

```
create table CustomerDetails.Clients (
Client_ID int primary key identity (100, 10),
Company_Name varchar (35) not null, 
Contact_Person char (35) not null,
City char (20) not null, 
State char (20) not null,
Zip int not null,
Country char (45) not null,
Phone varchar (30) not null
CONSTRAINT chk_Phone CHECK 
(Phone like '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9] [0-9][0-9]-[0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9]-[0-9] [0-9] [0-9]')
);

insert into CustomerDetails.Clients values ('Bazz Beauty Home', 'Felix Jhean', 
    'Ohio', 'Cincinnati', '350056', 'United States', '34-453-5458-698-978')
```

Answer (score 1):

`34-453-5458-698-978` is 19 characters long, but your phone number column is `varchar(18)`.  You should increase the length of your Phone column.

Comment: Thanks. I've done that. I've made it 30 now. I have a problem with the check constraint.

Comment: Right, the check constraint assumes 18 characters too.  You could allow multiple formats with `check (phone like '...' or phone like '...' or ...)`, or you could use [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) like `_` and `%`

Comment: @Shayooluwah looking at your contraint, then you want a number like `'00-0 00-0 000-00 0-0 0 0'`. The number in your `INSERT` (`'34-453-5458-698-978'`) is nothing like that formatting. To start with, it has no white space.

Comment: @Larnu Ok. How do i make the insert to look like the specified constraint

Comment: Considering you have a literal string, @Shayooluwah then type it in the correct format. Unless you mean you want a `CONSTRAINT` that matches your string literal? However, you're`CONSTRAINT` is expecting 14 digits, and your literal has 15. They are, quite simply, fundamentally different.

Comment: @Larnu I guess the constraint is ok. But i dont really understand it. Cause i copied it from somewhere and edited it to what I wanted.                          
Phone must be in the format: ‘[0-9][0-9]-[0-9] [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9]-[0-9] [0-9]  [0-9]. That's what i want the constraint to do, i think its already doing that. I'm just having problems making my insert match the constraint

Comment: I would suggest you don't understand the Constraint then @Shayooluwah. My comment above shows you the expected format (according to that constraint). If you can't write your phone numbers in the format, then the constraint isn't right.

Comment: @Larnu. Thanks a billion. I followed your format and it worked. I should open a temple and worship you if i could, thanks a billion

Comment: @Larnu what if i wanted the constraint to check for the phone number in this format 11-111-1111-111-111

Comment: Have a try and post your attempt @Shayooluwah